# Help with writing an AppleScript to navigate to profiles and double click the first profile

Tags: applescript, automator, ventura

I'm new to AppleScript and I'm trying to write one that opens System Settings in macOS Ventura, navigate to the Profiles pane (or at least it used to be called that) and double click the first profile (which on my test machine I'm expecting to already be there).

I've tried using Automator to do this, but the AppleScript it creates just opens system settings, clicks Privacy & Security and then crashes. See below for generated applescript and the failure I get when I try to run it:

Generated Applescript

```
on run {input, parameters}
    -- Click “System Settings” in the Dock.
    delay 0.962111
    set timeoutSeconds to 2.000000
    set uiScript to "click UI Element \"System Settings\" of list 1 of application process \"Dock\""
    my doWithTimeout( uiScript, timeoutSeconds )

    -- Click the text “Privacy & Security”
    delay 1.279727
    set timeoutSeconds to 2.000000
    set uiScript to "click static text 1 of UI Element 1 of row 18 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window \"Appearance\" of application process \"System Settings\""
    my doWithTimeout( uiScript, timeoutSeconds )

    -- Drag the scroll thumb in the scroll area.
    delay 1.556507
    set timeoutSeconds to 2.000000
    set uiScript to "click scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window \"Privacy & Security\" of application process \"System Settings\""
    my doWithTimeout( uiScript, timeoutSeconds )

    -- Drag the scroll thumb in the scroll area.
    delay 0.739944
    set timeoutSeconds to 2.000000
    set uiScript to "click scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window \"Privacy & Security\" of application process \"System Settings\""
    my doWithTimeout( uiScript, timeoutSeconds )

    -- Click the “<fill in title>” button.
    delay 0.674634
    set timeoutSeconds to 2.000000
    set uiScript to "click UI Element 2 of group 6 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window \"Privacy & Security\" of application process \"System Settings\""
    my doWithTimeout( uiScript, timeoutSeconds )

    -- Click the text “Settings for name’s Mac”
    delay 1.596732
    set timeoutSeconds to 2.000000
    set uiScript to "click static text 1 of UI Element 1 of row 2 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window \"Profiles\" of application process \"System Settings\""
    my doWithTimeout( uiScript, timeoutSeconds )

    -- Click the text “Settings for name’s Mac”
    delay 0.073788
    set timeoutSeconds to 2.000000
    set uiScript to "click static text 1 of UI Element 1 of row 2 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window \"Profiles\" of application process \"System Settings\""
    my doWithTimeout( uiScript, timeoutSeconds )
    return input
end run

on doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)
    set endDate to (current date) + timeoutSeconds
    repeat
        try
            run script "tell application \"System Events\"
" & uiScript & "
end tell"
            exit repeat
        on error errorMessage
            if ((current date) > endDate) then
                error "Can not " & uiScript
            end if
        end try
    end repeat
end doWithTimeout
```

Watch me do the actions that generates the AppleScript:

[image]

Error I get when I run it:

[image]

EDIT: Ok i replaced all the navigation with a shell script that opens the profiles pane, now i just need to figure out why the double click doesnt work:
[image]

Error i get now:
[image]

Comment: Also i saw someone edit my post to make the pictures smaller, how do i do that?

Comment: Images upload to imgur, who automatically make 3 other versions, s, m, l. It's just a case of changing the link. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165795/how-to-make-pictures-smaller/165797#165797  and also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319001/sizing-images-in-posts-original-size-in-link

Comment: I resized your latest images - but I didn't do the click-through for full size, as in the second link. They're more useful for high-detail or very large images.